# Extract data and compute

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have about 900 rows in excel and need to parse and compute specific information from each row into another row.

An example row is:

System xyz has 4 x 10TB of data assigned to client.

I need to be able to find the 4 x 10TB and compute it to be 40TB in a separate column. However, some people note it as 4x10TB or 4 x 10 TB or 4 x 10TB. Some data is only GB.

Is there a formula to use to at least extract the storage?

Comment: With excel a solution would be regex.. It's not realy easy to deal with them and to implement them..
This link could help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744602/how-do-you-execute-a-regular-expression-in-excel

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood...  What do you mean "data comes from a notes field?"  I thought you meant it's in a comment, but perhaps you just mean it's free-form, and thus hard to match on?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a notes field from the database. No one entered the sizes in a separate column. In excel, the extract of my example is in one column.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add 4 columns, to make this easier to trouble shoot and perform math/conversions on later.

1. String to parse
2. Count
3. Size
4. Unit of Measure (TB or GB)

The **"String to parse"** is the relevant section of the note that we need to calculate from.  Regular expressions can help you here.

Add a user defined function for Regular expressions as noted here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744602/how-do-you-execute-a-regular-expression-in-excel

I think the regex you want is:

```
"[0-9 x]*[GT]B"
```

which will return as follows given these strings (after stripping all spaces):

```
BOB HAS 400 x 10   gB --> "400x10gB"
4x10TB IN THE building xx --> "4x10TB"
I have 20TB of space --> "20TB"
```

So, to get this **"String to parse"**, let's say you put this in B2 with a target cell A2:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(udfRegEx(A2,"[0-9 x]*[GT]B")," ","")
```

**Count** can be extracted with (note it populates this as 1, when no multiple is supplied):

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("x",B2)),1,VALUE(LEFT(B2,FIND("x",B2)-1)))
```

**Size** can be extracted with:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("x",B2)),VALUE(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-2)),VALUE(MID(B2,FIND("x",B2)+1,LEN(B2)-2-FIND("x",B2))))
```

**Unit of Measure** (TB or GB) with:

```
=UPPER(RIGHT(B2,2))
```

Count and Size are both returned as numbers, so you should be able to multiply and add from there...

Note, a single VBA function could have done all this and hidden much of the complexity, but I think it's best to leave VBA functions as generic as possible, and do the rest in excel if reasonable.